# Localization with django

Tags: django, localization, translation

I have similar code as the below everywhere in my code:

```
s_message = gettext.translation('django', locale_directory(), [langcode],\
fallback=True).ugettext('Hi %(username)s....' % {'username': s_usr}) 

s_message_title = gettext.translation('django', locale_directory(), [langcode],\
fallback=True).ugettext('Error Message') 

s_message_btn = gettext.translation('django', locale_directory(), [langcode], \
fallback=True).ugettext('OK')
```

...and I want to write a function that wraps it up likewise:

```
build_msg_dict(m='Hi %(username)s....', lc=langcode, \
m_params={'username': s_usr}, button_list=['OK'], t='Error Message', \
m_type=MESSAGE_TYPE__ERROR)
```

Problem is that following this change of replacing the above sample 3 lines of code with 1 call to this function, whenever I run:

```
django-admin.py makemessages
```

...it now never "collects" the text for translation and adds it to django.po. I know why but I am a bit puzzled what is the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution for this, ended up calling the function likewise:

```
build_msg_dict(m=ugettext('Hi %(username)s....'), lc=langcode, \
m_params={'username': s_usr}, button_list=[ugettext('OK')], t=ugettext('Error Message'), \
m_type=MESSAGE_TYPE__ERROR)
```

Inside build_msg_dict function, I simply do str(m) and str(t) to get the original text in English.